# Groovy based BDD in Spring

Tags: spring, groovy, osgi, bdd

we're planing to build a system based on spring and we would like to use a groovy based BDD framework. The system is also OSGi based.

Any suggestion for a good BDD framework which also fit into the STS eclipse from spring.?

How would you work with mocks in such a environment? OSGi needs to mock a lot of the external dependencies.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe stupid ... but what is bdd?

Comment: Behaviour Driven Development

Answer (score 2):

[The Spock testing framework](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/) is a powerful BDD-inspired testing framework based on Groovy. 
It has a lot of features and might be exactly what your looking for.

Don't be put off by the low version number (current version is 0.7), it has been stable and production ready for a long time. I've been using it for at least a couple of years to test Java, Groovy, Griffon and Grails projects -- and wouldn't dream of going back...

It's built on top of JUnit and will run in every environment (at least that I'm aware of) where JUnit runs. It runs from within Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA as normal JUnit tests.

A very simple example (note: the comments after `expect:`, `where:` etc. are optional):

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class SpockExampleSpecification extends Specification {

    def "a String should return correct length"() {
        expect: "correct length"
        myString.length() == length

        where: "different strings have different lengths"
        myString    | length
        "hello"     | 5
        "abc"       | 3
        ""          | 0
    }

    def """show a string mock that could be injected into a class;
           using groovy metaClass, spring injection or any other means"""() {

        given: "a mock for char sequence, injected into DoubleLength"
        def mock = Mock(CharSequence)
        def dsl = new DoubleLength(myString: mock)

        when: "accessing lengths from this mock"
        def doubleLength = dsl.length()

        then: """mock value should be used and we should
                 get the expected interactions with the mock"""
        1 * mock.length() >> 1234
        doubleLength == 2468
    }

}
```

---

```
class DoubleLength {
    def myString

    def length() {
        2 * myString.length()
    }
}
```

Comment: I know spock but I don't like so much the syntax, I'd prefer easyb but somehow the website is down since a while

Comment: I don't have anything to add, except that the latest Spock version is 0.7 and comes with a greatly improved mocking framework. And for testing Spring applications, spock-spring might come in handy (full support for Spring TestContext framework).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: thanks - I've updated the version number to 0.7